# Implicit declaration of 'gets'

Tags: c, linux, gets

I understand that an 'implicit declaration' usually means that the function must be placed at the top of the program before calling it or that I need to declare the prototype.
However, `gets` should be in the `stdio.h` files (which I have included).
Is there any way to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);
   fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode
   if( fp == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: What's your code? How are you compiling it, and what is your reason for using gets?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for inspiration on how to produce example code

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are right that if you include proper headers, you shouldn't get the implicit declaration warning.

However, the function `gets()` has been *removed* from C11 standard. That means there's no longer a prototype for `gets()` in `<stdio.h>`. `gets()` *used to* be in `<stdio.h>`.

The reason for the removal of `gets()` is quite well known: It can't protect against the buffer overrun. As such, you should never use `gets()` and use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) instead and take care of the trailing newline, if any.

Comment: (If you are inetersted) The weird part is, even though it gives the error it is still able to run just fine.

Comment: That's probably because the libraries still have the function, possibly to avoid breaking ancient code. But no new code should ever use `gets()`.

Answer (score 17):

`gets()` was removed from the C11 standard.  Do not use it.
Here is a simple alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[1024];  // or whatever size fits your needs.

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
    // handle the input as you would have from gets
} else {
    // handle end of file
}
```

You can wrap this code in a function and use that as a replacement for `gets`:

```
char *mygets(char *buf, size_t size) {
    if (buf != NULL && size > 0) {
        if (fgets(buf, size, stdin)) {
            buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
            return buf;
        }
        *buf = '\0';  /* clear buffer at end of file */
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And use it in your code:

```
int main(void) {
    char file_name[25];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
    mygets(file_name, sizeof file_name);
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); // read mode
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use gets include <stdio.h> but like everyone said you're putting your program for a buffer overflow and exploitation. Use it only if you're testing an exploit case with this function.

Comment: @chqrlie Isn't `sizeof buf` or `sizeof file_name` missing parenthesis ? And why do you need the size has an external parameter of `mygets` instead of doing `size=sizeof(buf)` inside your `mygets` function ?

Comment: @SebMa: parentheses are only required when the argument of `sizeof` is a type. For an expression, `sizeof` behaves as a prefix operator. I only use optional parentheses when I use `sizeof` in an expression such as `sizeof(*buf) * 10` but even in this expression, the parentheses are optional and redundant.

Comment: @SebMa: regarding the `size` argument for `mygets`, it is required because the size of the array pinted to by `buf` cannot be determined from the pointer itself. `sizeof(buf)` is just the size of the pointer, not that of the array.