# why i can't input 2nd book title name?

Tags: c, structure

When i Compile this program then i can't input book2.title name,
is it fault about using gets funtion then why?
please explain it more ...........................

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct name{
char author[20];
char title[20];
float price;
};
int main()
{
    struct name book1,book2;
    printf("Enter 1st title name:");
    gets(book1.title);
    printf("Enter 1st Author name:");
    gets(book1.author);
    printf("Enter 1st Book price:");
    scanf("%f",&book1.price);
    printf("\nThe 1st Book Name is %s",book1.title);
    printf("\nThe 1st Book Author is %s",book1.author);
    printf("\nThe 1st Book Price is %f",book1.price);
    printf("\nEnter 2nd title name:");
    gets(book2.title);
    printf("Enter 2nd Author name:");
    gets(book2.author);
    printf("Enter 2nd Book price:");
    scanf("%f",&book2.price);

    printf("\nThe 2nd Book Name is %s",book2.title);
    printf("\nThe 2nd Book Author is %s",book2.author);
    printf("\nThe 2nd Book Price is %f",book2.title);
     return 0;


}
```

Comment: Did you look at the compiler warnings? For example, this line `printf("\nThe 2nd Book Price is %f",book2.title);` wants to print a float, but is given a string.

Comment: Please think about how someone who might want to help you encounter this question.

Comment: Also, regarding your usage of `gets` instead of `scanf`: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031514/implicit-declaration-of-gets

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: Please provide more information. Your current question contains almost no useful information to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two problems unrelated to your question:

- The use of gets
- The use of `%f` in `printf` for a string.

However, the behavior leading to your question lies in these two lines:

```
scanf("%f",&book1.price);
...
gets(book2.title);
```

Note, when you enter the book1 price (say 12.3) in the terminal, you press enter afterwards. Therefore, the `stdin` buffer holds the characters `12.3\n`. The scanf reads the first few bytes which it can interpret as a float `12.3`, leaving the buffer holding `\n`. Now, when you run `gets`, it reads the newline, and your 2nd book's title is the blank string "\0".

See this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-with-scanf-when-there-is-fgetsgetsscanf-after-it/

**Note: Please, please use fgets/scanf/getline instead of gets.** For more information, see the link posted by @RobertS in the comments above.

Comment: While it's sugar coating, you do not need to refer to my comment. Just linking will do its work. :-)

Comment: I agree that I should put it more constructively. Edited. I did write that part because the author clearly did not put the effort into reading the warnings during compilation.

Comment: You could hint the ignored warnings especially. (No need to show the exact warnings, but describe that OP apparently either disabled or ignored them). BTW OP did not specified their compiler, maybe not even a standard-compliant one, which do not show any warnings at all.

Comment: P.S.: Do you know how you can link to comments?